# Burninate [resignfirstresponder]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[resignfirstresponder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resignfirstresponder) (113 questions) references a method `resignFirstResponder` which is used primarily to dismiss the keyboard.

I believe this falls under: [Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191)
The questions are not "**actually about the concept represented by the tag**" ; the method is not a concept so I think it should be burninated (emphasis mine from linked post).

Is that sufficient cause to burninate the tag?

Comment: This tag passes all 4 tests that Shog mentions; the "concept represented by the tag" is, in this case that method. Do the questions that use this tag reference that method?

Comment: The concept would be the [tag:first-responder].

Comment: You're reading too much into the word concept in this case. The questions are about tithing the tag is - that makes it not a bad tag compared to some out there. From your response, though, you're asking for it to be synonymised to a different tag rather than being removed altogether?

Comment: This seems like too localized of a tag.  I think the questions should be merged into the tag for the class that contains this method, [UIResponder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uiresponder).

Comment: Not synonymised, single retagged when the question deals with the UIResponder chain.